# Uniqueness of Riesz Representation of $C^{*}[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem, stieltjes-integral

I have seen this statement: The dual space $C^{*}\left[a,b\right]$ of $C\left[a,b\right]$ is isometrically isomorphic to $BV_{0}\left[a,b\right]$.
where $$BV_{0}\left[a,b\right]=\left\{ \alpha\in BV\left[a,b\right]|\alpha\left(a\right)=0,\alpha\text{ right-continuous on}\left(a,b\right)\right\} $$

Now I want to show:

For $T\in C^{*}\left[a,b\right]$, if there exists a $\alpha\in BV_{0}\left[a,b\right]$ such that $T=T_{\alpha}$. That is, $$T\left(f\right)=T_{\alpha}\left(f\right)=\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha$$

for all $f\in C\left[a,b\right]$. then $\left\Vert T\right\Vert =T_{a}^{b}\left(\alpha\right)$. And if there exists $\alpha,\beta\in BV_{0}\left[a,b\right]$ such that $T=T_{\alpha}=T_{\beta}$. Then $\alpha=\beta$ on $\left[a,b\right]$.

I have prove that $\left\Vert T_{\alpha}\right\Vert \le T_{a}^{b}\left(\alpha\right)$, but I have trouble proving $\left\Vert T_{\alpha}\right\Vert \geq T_{a}^{b}\left(\alpha\right)$ and the uniqueness, could anyone give some help?

Comment: For proving uniqueness, you might want to consider the Dirac delta function, and how it can be considered a limit of continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with $T \in C[a,b]^*$, then you can extend $T$ to $S \in L^{\infty}[a,b]*
$ in such a way that $\|S\| = \|T\|$. Then $S$ is defined on step functions such as $\chi_{[a,b]}$ and $\chi_{[a,b)}$, etc.. For any positive integer $N$, let
$$
       x_0 = a, \; x_1 = a+\frac{b-a}{N}, x_2=a+2\frac{b-a}{N},\cdots, x_N=b.
$$
For any $f\in C[a,b]$ define $f_N$ to be
$$
          f_N = f(x_0)\chi_{[x_0,x_1)}+f(x_1)\chi_{[x_1,x_2)}+\cdots+f(x_{N-1})\chi_{[x_{N-1},x_N]}.
$$
Then $f_N\rightarrow f$ in $L^{\infty}[a,b]$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$ because $f\in C[a,b]$. Define $\alpha(t)=S(\chi_{[a,t)})$ for $a \le t < b$ and let $\alpha(b)=S(1)$. Then $\alpha$ is of bounded variation and there are unimodular constants $c_n$ such that
$$
       \sum_{n=1}^{N}|\alpha(t_n)-\alpha(t_{n-1})|=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}c_nS(\chi_{[t_{n-1},t_n)})+c_NS(\chi_{[t_{N-1},t_{N}]}) \\
   = S\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}c_n\chi_{[t_{n-1},t_{n})}+C_N\chi_{[t_{N-1},t_N]}\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
     \sum_{n=1}^{N}|\alpha(t_n)-\alpha(t_{n-1})| \le \|S\|=\|T\|.
$$
So $\alpha$ is of bounded variation and $V_{a}^{b}(\alpha) \le \|T\|$. Furthermore,
$$
      T(f)=\lim_{N} S(f_N)=\lim_N \sum_{n=1}^{N}f(x_n)\Delta\alpha_n = \int_{a}^{b}f(t)d\alpha(t) \\
         |T(f)| \le \|f\|_{C[a,b]}V_{a}^{b}(\alpha) \\
     \|T\| \le V_{a}^{b}(\alpha).
$$
So $\|T\|=V_a^b(\alpha)$. Modiffying $\alpha$ to be left- or right-continuous will not increase its variation, or the representation of $T(f)=\int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha$. So it still follows that $\|T\|=V_a^b(\tilde{\alpha})$, where $\tilde{\alpha}$ is left- or right- continuous.